# Remove Readonly attr from SELECT

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a click event that is triggered when a user clicks on a `select` element that has a `readonly` state. This works fine.

The problem I have is that when the `readonly` state is removed from the `select` element, the click event is still present.

**[Here is a DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/afjoy8ff/1/)**.

You will notice that when you click the `select` element, the top function still runs even though the `select` is no longer `readonly`

```
$('select[readonly]').on("click", function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  alert('This is readonly!');
});

$('button').on("click", function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  $('#div form select').attr("readonly", false);
  alert('Readonly Attr Removed!');
});
```

Is there a way around this issue? I know I could accomplish this with some way of adding/removing a class - but i'd rather not have that approach.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've got two problems.

**First**

`select[readonly]` will target a select that has the attribute `readonly`, also when it is false. To fix that, use `removeAttr('readonly')`.

**Second**

The select already got the click event binded on it. So instead, bind the function on the form, with a filter.

All together:

```js
$('form').on("click", 'select[readonly]', function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  alert('This is readonly!');
});

$('button').on("click", function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  $('#div form select').removeAttr("readonly");

  alert('Readonly Attr Removed!');
});
```

```css
select[readonly] {
  background-color: red; 
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="div">
  <form>
    <div class="form-group">
      <select readonly>
      <option>Select an option</option>
      <option>option 2</option>
      <option>option 3</option>
      </select>
    </div>
  </form>
</div>
<br /><br />
<button>
Remove Disabled Attr
</button>
```

Or the [updated Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/afjoy8ff/4/)

Comment: This is right. The key here was the filter. Thanks. I'll mark it as correct.

Answer (score 4):

You need just to use event delegation `.on()` instead so it will take in consideration the DOM change made by the button click :

```
$('body').on("click",'select[readonly]', function(e) {
```

Hopet his helps.

```js
$('body').on("click",'select[readonly]', function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  alert('This is readonly!');
});

$('button').on("click", function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  $('#div form select').attr("readonly", false);

  alert('Readonly Attr Removed!');
});
```

```css
select[readonly] {
  background-color: red; 
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="div">
  <form>
    <div class="form-group">
      <select readonly="true">
        <option>Select an option</option>
        <option>option 2</option>
        <option>option 3</option>
      </select>
    </div>
  </form>
</div>
<br /><br />
<button>
  Remove Disabled Attr
</button>
```

Comment: Thanks @steve for your intervention.. Updated my answer, in fact you don't need to change `.attr("readonly", false);` just event delegation will do the trick.

Comment: This didn't post the solution first. The first solution didn't work. Only since the edit (which is the same as the correct answer). I only chose the other answer because he posted the correct solution first. I've +1 this answer too.

Answer (score 2):

Since `readonly` is a property, You should use [`.prop(propertyName, value)`](http://api.jquery.com/prop/#prop2)

> Set one or more properties for the set of matched elements.

```
$('#div form select').prop("readonly", false);
```

---

You should use `disabled` property instead of `readonly`, then you don't need bind/unbind the event handler.

```
<select disabled>
</select>
```

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/8c1tcp8b/)

Comment: @BharatPatidar, Updated answer with fiddle

Comment: Hi still going in wrong direction check it again partial right

Answer (score 2):

I think you need to remove the onClick event, as it's already added to the list. no matter you change the attribute Readonly, the "onclick" event will run anyway.

You can check this jQuery method http://api.jquery.com/off/ to remove on click event handler.

Comment: You should do both, just to be technically precise.

Comment: I think according to the jQuery flow "onclick" action is added to the element no matter any of its attributes is changing the action will be there .... But ofcourse if you want to remove readonly as well, this will not harm

Answer (score 1):

A better solution will be to use a class,the readonly property will not stop the click event :

```
$('body').on("click",'select:not(.active)', function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  alert('This is readonly!');
});

$('button').on("click", function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  $('#div form select').addClass("active");
  $('#div form select').removeAttr('readonly');
  alert('Readonly Attr Removed!');
});
```

```js
$('body').on("click",'select:not(.active)', function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  alert('This is readonly!');
});

$('button').on("click", function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  $('#div form select').addClass("active");
  $('#div form select').removeAttr('readonly');
  alert('Readonly Attr Removed!');
});
```

```css
select[readonly] {
  background-color: red; 
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="div">
  <form>
    <div class="form-group">
      <select readonly="true">
        <option>Select an option</option>
        <option>option 2</option>
        <option>option 3</option>
      </select>
    </div>
  </form>
</div>
<br /><br />
<button>
  Remove Disabled Attr
</button>
```